# Why does .hginore fail to ignore files in the subdirectory I'm trying to specify

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

I've created a .hgignore file in the following way:

```
syntax: glob

*/Images/*pgm
```

which I had hoped would ignore all .pgm files in any subdirectory of my Images directory. However, it does not ignore them.

When I create the following .hginore file, pgm files are ignored

```
syntax: glob

*pgm
```

Why doesn't my more targeted attempt work? (Note: There are other ignore patterns in my file, which I have omitted)

Comment: That's not how globbing works. `*` never expands to include a `/` splitting to a subdirectory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `**` pattern matches any string, and crosses directory boundaries (while `*` does not).

Try with:

```
**/Images/**pgm
```